# Combining two accounts

Tags: java

This is a homework assignment. I need to consolidate the two accounts (acct2 and acct3) and produce a third one with the same name, different account number and $200. I also have to close the first two accounts. That is not really the issue though. I can get everything to work fine if I do not declare public static Account accountConsolidate(Account acct1, Account acct2) as a static method, and just create an object in the main. This does not work though because I am required to declare this method as static. Also, if I do declare it as static I can get the proper return value in the `if(acct1.name.equalsIgnoreCase(acct2.name)  && acct1.acctNum != acct2.acctNum)` if I exclude the
`&& acct1.acctNum != acct2.acctNum
 other wise it will return null ("These two accounts are not able to be consolidated. Please check the criteria again", not sure why.

Any help would be great. Thanks

```
import java.util.Random;

    public class Account
    {
        private static int numAccounts = 0;
        private double balance;
        private static String name;
        private static double acctNum;
        static Random gen = new Random();

    //-------------------------------------------------
    //Constructor -- initializes balance, owner, and account number
    //-------------------------------------------------
        public Account(double initBal, String owner, double number)
        {
            balance = initBal;
            name = owner;
            acctNum = number;
            numAccounts++;
        }

        public Account(double initBal, String owner)
        {
            balance = initBal;
            name = owner;
            acctNum =  Math.abs(gen.nextDouble());
            numAccounts++;
        }

        public Account(String owner)
        {
            balance = 0;
            name = owner;
            acctNum =  Math.abs(gen.nextDouble());
            numAccounts++;
        }

    //-------------------------------------------------
    // Checks to see if balance is sufficient for withdrawal.
    // If so, decrements balance by amount; if not, prints message.
    //-------------------------------------------------
        public void withdraw(double amount)
        {
            if (balance >= amount)
            {   
                balance -= amount;
            }   
            else
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
        }

        public void withdraw(double amount, double fee)
        {
            if (balance >= amount)
                {
                    balance -= amount;
                    balance -= fee; 
                }   
            else
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds");   
        }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public double getNum()
    {
        return acctNum;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------
    // Adds deposit amount to balance.
    //-------------------------------------------------
        public void deposit(double amount)
        {
            balance += amount;
        }

    //-------------------------------------------------
    // Returns balance.
    //-------------------------------------------------
        public double getBalance()
        {
            return balance;
        }

    // Static method to keep track of incrementing Account
        public static int getNumAccounts()
        {
            return numAccounts;
        }

    // Close the account
        public void close()
        {
            balance = 0;
            name = "CLOSED";
            numAccounts--;
        }


    // Consolidate accounts
        public static Account accountConsolidate(Account acct1, Account acct2)
        {

            if(acct1.name.equalsIgnoreCase(acct2.name)  && acct1.acctNum != acct2.acctNum)
            {
                Account Account2 = new Account(0, acct1.name);
                Account2.balance = acct1.getBalance() + acct2.getBalance(); 
                acctNum = Math.abs(gen.nextDouble());

                acct1.close();
                acct2.close();  
                return Account2;

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("These two accounts are not able to be consolidated. Please check the criteria again");
                return null;
            }   
        }

    //-------------------------------------------------
    // Returns a string containing the name, account number, and balance.
    //-------------------------------------------------
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Name:" + name +
                "\nAccount Number: " + acctNum +
                "\nBalance: " + balance;
        }
    }

//************************************************************
//TestAccounts1
//A simple program to test the numAccts method of the
//Account class.
//************************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TestAccount1
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String name1;
            String name2;
            String name3;

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Please enter the name for account 1: ");
            name1 = scan.nextLine();
            Account acct1 = new Account (100, name1);
            System.out.println(acct1);
            System.out.println("Now there are " + Account.getNumAccounts() + " accounts");
            System.out.println("");

            System.out.print("Please enter the name for account 2: ");
            name2 = scan.nextLine();
            Account acct2 = new Account (100, name2);
            System.out.println(acct2);
            System.out.println("Now there are " + Account.getNumAccounts() + " accounts");
            System.out.println("");

            System.out.print("Please enter the name for account 3: ");
            name3 = scan.nextLine();
            Account acct3 = new Account (100, name3);
            System.out.println(acct3);
            System.out.println("Now there are " + Account.getNumAccounts() + " accounts");
            System.out.println("");

            acct1.close();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("There are now "  + Account.getNumAccounts() + " accounts");


            System.out.println("Accounts consolidated");
            System.out.println(Account.accountConsolidate(acct2, acct3));
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your specific question ?

Comment: Why can I do perform this without the static method, using an object and not the other way around? Also, why does it work using static but only when && acct1.acctNum != acct2.acctNum is omitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your account numbers are randomly generated but the `accNum` is static. So every account will have the created account number of the last account. So `acct1.acctNum != acct2.acctNum` will always be false.

Your account name is static as well, so each account will have the account name of the last created account.

After you changed this read your compiler errors. It will tell you what to do next. Think about which variables of which object you will modify. Like `acctNum = Math.abs(gen.nextDouble());` will not set the account number of your consolidated account `Account2`.

Comment: I have no issue with compiling. This is what I . Please enter the name for account 1: nolan
Name:nolan
Account Number: 0.38784176303522233
Balance: 100.0
Now there are 1 accounts

Please enter the name for account 2: nolan
Name:nolan
Account Number: 0.884383874274763
Balance: 100.0
Now there are 2 accounts

Please enter the name for account 3: nolan
Name:nolan
Account Number: 0.23193417654313297
Balance: 100.0
Now there are 3 accounts


There are now 2 accounts
Accounts consolidated
These two accounts are not able to be consolidated. Please check the criteria again
null

Comment: You will after changing the variables to non static.

Comment: When I do that It just tells me to change acctNum back to static because "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field acctNum" I figured this was because the accountConsolidate method is static. Maybe I am missing something... I appreciate your time

Comment: Correct. But whom does this variable belong to? To `acct1`, `acct2`, `Account2` or some other object? The compiler doesn't know because a static method doesn't belong to an object. So you have to use the correct object whose variable should be changed.

Comment: You are a genius! Sorry for such a noob question. Thank you for you help!

Comment: You are welcome. We all have started at zero and had to ask such questions to become good. Please mark this question as solved by clicking the check mark on the left of my answer.